# Show that the defined following function is a ring homomorpism

Tags: ring-theory

Let $g:\Bbb Z_2 [x] \to \Bbb Z_2$ defined by $g(f(x)) = f(\bar{1})$ for all $f(x) \in \Bbb Z_2[x]$ and $\bar{1} \in \Bbb Z_2$.
What is $Ker \ g$?
Is it:
$Ker g = \{f(x) \in \Bbb Z_2[x] \mid f(\bar{1}) = \bar(0)\}$?

Then, how to show it is surjective?

Comment: $f(1)=0\iff f(x)\in (x-1)$

Answer (score 0):

It is surjective because $g(1)=1$.

Comment: How about its Kernel, Sir?

Comment: $g$ is surjective because there is exist $\bar{1} \in \Bbb Z_2$ such that for all $f(x) \in \Bbb Z_2[x], g(f(x)) = g(1)=1$. Like this?

Comment: Let $f(x):=1$.  The kernel is everything that is zero when evaluated at $1$.  So, everything such that $f(1)$ is even.  That would be everything with an even number of nonzero terms.  Also, since the kernel is not the whole ring, it is surjective.

Comment: How can it be $g(1)=1$?

Comment: since $g(f(x)) = f(1)$. How to get that?

Comment: How can we let $f(x):= 1$ for all $x \in R$?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Z_2$.